# Regaining efficiency on older iPad

Tags: ipad, performance

I still have the very first retina iPad. Purely from empirical comparison, I have the impression that it has gradually become slower. At this point it is sometimes irritatingly slow, even for trivial -open-google's-maps-app- actions.

Are there any reports that this is connected to the recent old-iPhone-slowdown issues? Are there any reports of how I can regain the use of this iPad as simply a web browser and simple apps platform?

Comment: What iOS is it running? If pre-11, then the slowdown wasn't implemented, if post-11, there will be a 'battery vs slow' switch in the next release, afaik.

Comment: @Tetsujin if the device is "the very first retina iPad", then it would be the third-generation iPad with 32-bit A5X. It can run up to iOS 9.3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand, you have a third generation iPad, which has an A5X processor. This is a fairly old CPU, as it was released in early 2012, but it should still provide a decent experience for web browsing.

Note that the A5X is 32-bit, meaning it cannot run a lot of new apps or iOS releases that are deigned for 64-bit devices. The latest version of iOS you can run is iOS 9.3.5, so I would first suggest you update to that version to get the most secure and stable experience possible on that device.

To address the iPhone throttling, [iMore says that this does not affect iPads.](https://www.imore.com/no-ipad-slow)
According to iMore, Apple only stated that a handful of iPhone models (devices from the iPhone 6 to iPhone 7 Plus) will be throttled at all. iMore also points out that the larger batteries in iPads makes this less of an issue.

If your iPad seems to be slow, I would suggest you connect it to a Mac or Windows PC and use iTunes to [backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht203977#itunes) and [restore](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252) the device. This will ensure a clean and up to date installation of iOS. While this may help, your iPad is a bit old, and it may just not perform well on recent versions of iOS. If you're willing to upgrade, the [9.7" iPad](https://www.apple.com/ipad-9.7/) is a great option for its price and performance.